# How long is too long to condition a beer in secondary without having to pitch bottling yeast?

Tags: bottling, conditioning, secondary-fermentation

How long is too long to condition a beer in secondary without having to pitch bottling yeast?
What factors do I need to consider when deciding whether or not to pitch yeast at bottling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Time is one factor and strength is another.  For average strength (up to maybe 1.070) beers, 2-3 months is no problem.  For beer over that very much, I'd add yeast at maybe 3 months of age.

Comment: Is there any way to tell if I need to or not?

Comment: Just the general ROT I gave above.

Answer (score 1):

I had a couple of scottish ales that sat in both primary and secondary for a month (total of 2 months each), and they both carbonated with no additional yeast.   One was a 60/- and the other was a Wee-Heavy.   Neither of them was cooled below ~55F before I bottled, though.

I'd say it depends on alcohol content and the amount of CO<sub>2</sub> you want to put into the beer, though.  For something like a strong Saison or Belgian Golden Strong, where you want 3-4 volumes of CO<sub>2</sub>, it might be necessary.